# comparing to date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

hi guys I am dealing with this problem! it is hard for me! I really need help with this, this is what you will be see in the UI,

```
   Date Availing the Reservation: 9/12/2016(current date)
   Date Needed: mm/dd/yyyy
   Date of the Event: 9/26/2016(date 2 weeks from now)
   Date Reservation will Expire: 9/15/2016
```

What i want is that when the Date Needed is less than the current date it will show date should not be from the past, and if Date Needed is equal to date now until the date of the event which is 26 i am only valid to avail at 27 how will i do that? i have this logic:

```
   if($date_needed < $date_reserved &&  $date_needed > $date_of_the_event){
     echo "date must not be from the past and date of reservation must be 2 weeks from now";
   }
   else{
     echo "success!";
   }
```

This code didn't work well for me I mean, if I have this code, even thought I am putting the right code, it always comes up with error, i even else if this logic but it isn't working at all. can you help me with this? and my 2nd question is, I have this at my database: Date Reservation will Expire. I want if that day will come 9/15/2016. The row which has it, will automatically be deleted at the database or update it that is_active will be 0 how will I do that? thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You didn't show enough code. Where do $date_needed, $date_reserved, $date_needed, and $date_of_the_event come from? What are their values?

Comment: do you want validation on Client Side UI or at server side?

Comment: the values are those you see at the UI.

Comment: $date_needed is Date Needed
$date_reserved is Date of Availing the Reservation
and $date_of_the_event is Date of the Event

Comment: Are these numbers or strings (when comparing) not when displaying ...? What error do you observe? Prose talks about now comparisons are with event. Is now the event date?

Comment: the error is even though i put the date ahead or equal to the date of the event it still says it must be 2 weeks ahead or more

Answer (score 2):

**For Client Side validation** please review example : http://keith-wood.name/uidatepickervalidation.html

**For Server Side**

**Ans 1:** Simple way is convert dates in time and check how many days are left

```
$now = time();  //current date - Date Availing the Reservation
$your_date_needed = strtotime(date('YYYY-MM-DD'));
$datediff = $your_date_needed - $now;
$daysLeft = round($datediff/(60*60*24));
if($daysLeft>0) {
    echo "success! ".$daysLeft;
} else {
    echo "date should not be from the past";
}
```

**Ans 2:** You need to create a php file with same logic and then you can use [Cron Job](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428)

Comment: how will I make a logic with that thing sir? I mean I am not use to that thing and I do not know what is going on, how can i use that thing?